# Strange javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException, does not work with manual deploy but works in eclipse deploy

Tags: eclipse, jsf, deployment, wildfly, propertynotfoundexception

I'm having a problem to declare a property in a managed bean (JSF 2.2), I have already read other questions about name convention of property in beans and mine appears to be ok. My page.jsf is a ui composition and the property name is a date: `private Date dataSemAtendimento`. This is the calendar tag of primefaces (5.1) that I'm working with:

```
<p:dialog header="Escolha as data de feriado e ponto facultativo"
        widgetVar="modalCalendar" id="modalCalendar" modal="true" width="400"
        height="500" appendTo="@(body)">
        <p:calendar id="popup" widgetVar="popupCal"
            value="#{postoAtendimentoBean.dataSemAtendimento}">
        </p:calendar>
        <p:commandButton value="Adicionar data" update="tableCal">
            <p:ajax listener="#{postoAtendimentoBean.adicionarDataFeriado}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:dataList id="tableCal"
            value="#{postoAtendimentoBean.postoDiaSemAtendimentoList}" var="data"
            style="width:50%">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Datas que não ocorreram o atendimento
            </f:facet>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{data}">
                    <f:convertDateTime locale="pt" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" update="tableCal"
                    action="#{postoAtendimentoBean.removerDataFeriado(data)}">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{postoAtendimentoBean.removerDataFeriado(data)}"></p:ajax>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataList>
        <p:separator />
        <p:panelGrid style="margin: auto;">
            <p:commandButton value="Confirmar" onclick="PF('modalCalendar').hide();" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
```

And this is the managed bean code related to the get/setter:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PostoAtendimentoBean extends AbstractCRUDBean<PostoAtendimento, Long> {

    private Date dataSemAtendimento;

    public Date getDataSemAtendimento() {
        return dataSemAtendimento;
    }

    public void setDataSemAtendimento(Date dataSemAtendimento) {
        this.dataSemAtendimento = dataSemAtendimento;
    }

}
```

> Error Rendering View[/resources/template/template.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/cadastros/posto_atendimento/manter_posto_atendimento_persistencia.xhtml @161,25 value="#{postoAtendimentoBean.dataSemAtendimento}": The class 'br.com.webtech.scheduler.bean.postoatendimento.PostoAtendimentoBean' does not have the property 'dataSemAtendimento'.

I'm running in a wildfly (8.2.1) instance, but the strange thing is when I deploy it manually it doesn't work but when I deploy via eclipse adding the ear inside the server tab it works normally. I'm lost, already tried a couple of things. Any ideas? Thanks.

Another strange thing is, this started to happen when I changed the context-root of my application via Maven webModule tag.

Edit: I made a workaround by copying the .class with the wrong context-root and putting it inside the generated ear with the new context-root, that works but it's an awlful way to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you clean WildFly's work folders? It might have been corrupted and still contain an old version of the webapp/class. In `/standalone` folder, cleanup at least the `/tmp` and `/deployments` subfolders.

Comment: Already tried @BalusC I made a test with a new server folder using another version of wildfly and still got the same problem, works with eclipse but doesn't with manual deploy.

Comment: Another curious fact is that when I let the context-root setting by default without using maven tag, the application works.

Comment: I used a java decompiler to see the .class of PostoAtendimentoBean and the property dataSemAtendimento is not there

Comment: I'd say that clean and build went wrong. Answer depends on build tool used.